# Error tokenizing data. C error Panda read xlsx file

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv, xlsx

There are some questions with similar title as mine but none of them are answering my question.

I am trying to read the xlsx file which has the following format [image]

However I get the following error :`Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 3

I am not interested in reading the data section 1, section 2 or section 3 (However I have many file like this so I cannot remove them).I only want to read the data
starting the column1, column2,... column17. (Lets say removing the first 40 rows) Here is what I have tried:

```
data=pd.read_csv(Path)
```

> I get the Error tokenizing data. C error.

When I tried with header= None also I get the same thing.
I tried following:

```
data=pd.read_csv(Path,error_bad_lines=False)
```

> Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught

I tried following:

```
data=pd.read_csv(Path,names=[column1,column2,....column17])
```

I got this error

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf2 in position.

I do not know what encoding to use and do not think this is the problem. I  want to skip the 
first 40 lines of xlsx file as well and it seems I cannot change the engine to python and it only works by default engine. and read the data normally. Can anyone help me to load and read this data?
`

Update: After removing the section1, section2,... I still also I get tokenizing error. However removing the above sections make some files to columns to be corrupted maybe this is the case.

`
Update: File can be read using pd.read_excel(Path) by why I cannot read it using
pd.read_csv since that provides much more options that pd.read_excel?

Answer (score 1):

you can 
df=Pd.read_excel(path,skiprows=40)
What you were trying to achieve that Reading a excel file from read_csv that’s why it was giving thé error. You can use this and it won’t give the error

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
data = pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=40)
```

This would skip reading first 40 rows in the `.csv` file.

Comment: This did not work still gave me the same error. This is a xlsx file apparently so it has a problem with the encoding as well